# Events 8038 and 8020. The system failed to update DNS (error 9701)

Tags: networking, dns, samba, active-directory

When a pc boots it is unable to update it's DNS record. However, it works fine if you run `IPCONFIG /RENEW`, or `IPCONFIG /REGISTERDNS` or just leave it for a day.

**Setup:**

**Client**

- Clean Windows 10 install
- Fast Startup disabled
- Joined (Synology) Active Directory
- Computername: `C0156B.code54.lan`
- IP: `10.254.3.98`  (dhcp reservation)
- DNS server: `10.254.2.3`

**Server**

- Hostname: `nasa.code54.lan`  (btw. we are not the NASA, it's just NAS-A ;-))
- IP: `10.254.2.3`
- Synology running:

  - latest `DSM 7.1.1-42962 Update 6`
  - latest `Directory Server 4.15.9-0454` (implementation of Linux SAMBA)
  - latest `DNS server 9.16.23-6174`

**Router**
- DHCP: Draytek router, without any OPTIONs.

**My test**

1. PC has DHCP `10.254.3.99`
2. DNS registration is OK
3. PC is shutdown
4. DHCP registration is changed to `10.254.3.98` while PC is off.
5. PC is powered on.

It fails to update it's DNS from `10.254.3.99` to `10.254.3.98`.
It logs `Events 8038` and `8020`:

[image: Screenshot of Eventviewer]

The first is `Event 8038`:

```
The system failed to update and remove host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRs) for network adapter
with settings:

           Adapter Name : {DD45DC7D-BB94-493D-B734-BBF4A76B03D3}
           Host Name : C0156B
           Primary Domain Suffix : code54.lan
           DNS server list :
                10.254.2.3, 10.254.2.3
           Sent update to server : <?>
           IP Address(es) :
             10.254.3.99

The reason the update request failed was because of a system problem. See event details for specific error code information.
```

The "specific error code" is `9701`

Follow by `Event 8020`:

```
The system failed to register host (A or AAAA) resource records (RRs) for network adapter
with settings:

           Adapter Name : {DD45DC7D-BB94-493D-B734-BBF4A76B03D3}
           Host Name : C0156B
           Primary Domain Suffix : code54.lan
           DNS server list :
                10.254.2.3, 10.254.2.3
           Sent update to server : <?>
           IP Address(es) :
             10.254.3.98

The reason the system could not register these RRs during the update request was because of a system problem. You can manually retry DNS registration of the network adapter and its settings by typing 'ipconfig /registerdns' at the command prompt. If problems still persist, contact your DNS server or network systems administrator. See event details for specific error code information.
```

The "specific error code" is the same: `9701` which according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--9000-11999- means: `DNS_ERROR_RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST`.
However there is no DNS query issued at all.

This is a Wireshark capture of DNS traffic. It shows no Dynamic update, so the client doesn't perform any DNS query.

[image: Wireshark capture of DNS traffic]

and this is a log from Synology DNS-server:

```
2023/09/06 12:35:47.271 queries client @0x7f796404bbb8 10.254.3.98#60421 (download.windowsupdate.com): query: download.windowsupdate.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:42.088 queries client @0x7f797004c388 10.254.3.98#53427 (wpad.code54.lan): query: wpad.code54.lan IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:30.989 queries client @0x7f796c000c88 10.254.3.98#56650 (_kerberos._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.code54.lan): query: _kerberos._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.code54.lan IN SRV + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:28.588 queries client @0x7f796404bbb8 10.254.3.98#49343 (C0156B.code54.lan): query: C0156B.code54.lan IN SOA + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:28.584 queries client @0x7f796c000c88 10.254.3.98#59276 (C0156B.code54.lan): query: C0156B.code54.lan IN SOA + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:27.339 queries client @0x7f796c000c88 10.254.3.98#57615 (array506.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com): query: array506.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:27.331 queries client @0x7f796404bbb8 10.254.3.98#63469 (array511.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com): query: array511.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:27.328 queries client @0x7f7970010488 10.254.3.98#49646 (array502.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com): query: array502.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:26.947 queries client @0x7f796404bbb8 10.254.3.98#53062 (disc501.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com): query: disc501.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:26.874 queries client @0x7f7970010488 10.254.3.98#63048 (cp501.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com): query: cp501.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:26.797 queries client @0x7f79756a3958 10.254.3.98#51554 (kv501.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com): query: kv501.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:26.650 queries client @0x7f79756a3958 10.254.3.98#59659 (geo.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com): query: geo.prod.do.dsp.mp.microsoft.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:26.032 queries client @0x7f7970010488 10.254.3.98#64748 (_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.code54.lan): query: _ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.code54.lan IN SRV + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:25.898 queries client @0x7f79756a3958 10.254.3.98#54455 (code54.lan): query: code54.lan IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:25.442 queries client @0x7f79756a3958 10.254.3.98#59318 (_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.code54.lan): query: _ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.code54.lan IN SRV + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:24.624 queries client @0x7f796c000c88 10.254.3.98#59053 (nasa.code54.lan): query: nasa.code54.lan IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:24.599 queries client @0x7f79756a3958 10.254.3.98#59868 (_ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.code54.lan): query: _ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.code54.lan IN SRV + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:24.086 queries client @0x7f7970010488 10.254.3.98#49914 (dns.msftncsi.com): query: dns.msftncsi.com IN A + (10.254.2.3)
2023/09/06 12:35:23.576 queries client @0x7f796c000c88 10.254.3.98#64421 (wpad.code54.lan): query: wpad.code54.lan IN A + (10.254.2.3)
```

**Manual IPCONFIG /REGISTERNDS**

Manual update with `IPCONFIG /REGISTERDNS` works fine and indeed shows up in Wireshark:

[image: Wireshark of IPCONFIG /REGISTERDNS]

And this a DNS log of a successful manual update:

```
2023/09/06 12:06:41.822 database    samba_dlz: added rdataset C0156B.code54.lan 'C0156B.code54.lan. 1200 IN A 10.254.3.99'
2023/09/06 12:06:41.817 update  client @0x7f14dc0228e8 10.254.3.99#55121/key C0156B\$\@CODE54.LAN: updating zone 'code54.lan/NONE': adding an RR at 'C0156B.code54.lan' A 10.254.3.99
2023/09/06 12:06:41.816 database    samba_dlz: subtracted rdataset C0156B.code54.lan 'C0156B.code54.lan. 1200 IN A 10.254.3.98'
2023/09/06 12:06:41.813 update  client @0x7f14dc0228e8 10.254.3.99#55121/key C0156B\$\@CODE54.LAN: updating zone 'code54.lan/NONE': deleting rrset at 'C0156B.code54.lan' A
2023/09/06 12:06:41.812 update  client @0x7f14dc0228e8 10.254.3.99#55121/key C0156B\$\@CODE54.LAN: updating zone 'code54.lan/NONE': deleting rrset at 'C0156B.code54.lan' AAAA
2023/09/06 12:06:41.812 database    samba_dlz: allowing update of signer=C0156B\$\@CODE54.LAN name=C0156B.code54.lan tcpaddr=10.254.3.99 type=A key=1468-ms-7.1-1d62d3.12f3b826-4c9d-11ee-8d50-d89ef33763c7/160/0
2023/09/06 12:06:41.810 database    samba_dlz: allowing update of signer=C0156B\$\@CODE54.LAN name=C0156B.code54.lan tcpaddr=10.254.3.99 type=A key=1468-ms-7.1-1d62d3.12f3b826-4c9d-11ee-8d50-d89ef33763c7/160/0
2023/09/06 12:06:41.808 database    samba_dlz: allowing update of signer=C0156B\$\@CODE54.LAN name=C0156B.code54.lan tcpaddr=10.254.3.99 type=AAAA key=1468-ms-7.1-1d62d3.12f3b826-4c9d-11ee-8d50-d89ef33763c7/160/0
2023/09/06 12:06:40.030 queries client @0x7f14e16a3958 10.254.3.99#53427 (C0156B.code54.lan): query: C0156B.code54.lan IN SOA + (10.254.2.3)
```

I have also contacted Synology Support on this issue and they investigated the Wireshark files and a `tcpdump` on the NAS itself and confirmed that Windows is not doing an DNS update. So, as far as they're concerned, it's a Windows problem.

I am thinking along this way: Windows boots and is unaware of it's changed IP-address. Somehow it tries to find the combination of it's hostname and it's current (new) IP-address on the DNS server, which results in the `DNS_ERROR_RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST` error because the DNS server still holds the combination of the hostname with the old IP-address. Maybe Windows assumes that the DNS-record is already taken by another machine in stead of updating it, or something?

Comment: What is the DHCP server?

Comment: It's a Draytek router without OPTIONs. I added it to the description. Thanks. B.t.w. This is a repost of a question you already commented on. I remember your name ;-) I deleted the old question to focus on the error message and repeat the whole test.

Comment: I have answered that question and my opinion hasn't changed since. I mostly duplicated my old answer below. If you would prefer that I delete it then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your experience seems to be related to the Microsoft documentation for
[How to configure DNS dynamic updates in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-dns-dynamic-updates-windows-server-2003)
and especially the description starting from the section
[Integration of DHCP with DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-dns-dynamic-updates-windows-server-2003#integration-of-dhcp-with-dns).

I quote this text :

> **Integration of DHCP with DNS**
>
> A Windows DHCP server can enable dynamic updates in the DNS namespace
> for any one of its clients that support these updates. Scope clients
> can use the DNS dynamic update protocol to update their host
> name-to-address mapping information whenever changes occur to their
> DHCP-assigned address. This mapping information is stored in zones on
> the DNS server. A Windows-based DHCP server can perform updates on
> behalf of its DHCP clients to any DNS server.
>
> **How DHCP/DNS update interaction works**
>
> You can use the DHCP server to register and update the PTR and A
> resource records on behalf of the server's DHCP-enabled clients. When
> you do this, you must use an additional DHCP option, the Client FQDN
> option (option 81). This option lets the client send its FQDN to the
> DHCP server in the DHCPREQUEST packet. This enables the client to
> notify the DHCP server as to the service level it requires.

From the text, it seems that Windows expects
the DHCP server to participate in the DNS dynamic updates process.
It will only step in after executing an `ipconfig /registerdns`command.

I can't comment further on your environment (which is not mine),
but your experience might be normal.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not fully convinced that the update fails because of the DHCP server is not Windows. The article above says what a Windows DHCP server can do, not what happens when you don't use one. Hopefully someone else can confirm. I appreciate your answer however.